# Delete files (logs) older than one year in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my script I have (snippet):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
    ResultCode: integer;
    strLogFilePathName, strLogFileName, strNewFilePathName: string;
begin
    if (CurStep = ssDone) then
    begin
        strLogFilePathName := ExpandConstant('{log}');
        strLogFileName := ExtractFileName(strLogFilePathName);
        strNewFilePathName := ExpandConstant('{#CommonDataDir}\Installation Logs\') + strLogFileName;

        FileCopy(strLogFilePathName, strNewFilePathName, false);
    end
```

I have noticed that I now have installers going all the way back to 2021. What is the most appropriate way to keep this folder of files to, say the logs at most one year old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A code to delete all files last created/modified more than a year ago:

```pascal
type  
  TSystemTime = record 
    Year:         WORD; 
    Month:        WORD; 
    DayOfWeek:    WORD; 
    Day:          WORD; 
    Hour:         WORD; 
    Minute:       WORD; 
    Second:       WORD; 
    Milliseconds: WORD; 
  end;

function FileTimeToSystemTime(
    FileTime: TFileTime; var SystemTime: TSystemTime): Boolean; 
  external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

procedure GetSystemTime(var lpSystemTime: TSystemTime);
  external 'GetSystemTime@kernel32.dll';

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  strLogFilePathName, strLogFileName, strNewFilePathName: string;
  LogPath: string;
  FileSystemTime, CurrentTime: TSystemTime;  
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  if (CurStep = ssDone) then
  begin
    GetSystemTime(CurrentTime);

    LogPath := ExpandConstant('{#CommonDataDir}\Installation Logs\');

    if FindFirst(LogPath + '*', FindRec) then
    begin
      try
        repeat
          if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
          begin
            FileTimeToSystemTime(FindRec.LastWriteTime, FileSystemTime);
            if (FileSystemTime.Year < CurrentTime.Year - 1) or
               ((FileSystemTime.Year = CurrentTime.Year - 1) and
                (FileSystemTime.Month < CurrentTime.Month)) or
               ((FileSystemTime.Year = CurrentTime.Year - 1) and
                (FileSystemTime.Month = CurrentTime.Month) and
                (FileSystemTime.Day < CurrentTime.Day)) then
            begin
              Log(Format('Log %s is too old (%d.%d.%d), deleting...', [
                FindRec.Name, FileSystemTime.Day, FileSystemTime.Month,
                FileSystemTime.Year]));
              DeleteFile(LogPath + FindRec.Name);
            end
          end;
        until not FindNext(FindRec);
      finally
        FindClose(FindRec);
      end;
    end;

    strLogFilePathName := ExpandConstant('{log}');
    strLogFileName := ExtractFileName(strLogFilePathName);
    strNewFilePathName := LogPath + strLogFileName;

    FileCopy(strLogFilePathName, strNewFilePathName, false);
  end
end;
```

*Test well, before using on any important data!*